# SQL update statement shows emptie records

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add content to the database with this form. Everytime I submit I get an error that `$h_title`, `$b_title`, `$f_title` are `undefined` and my table shows up with empty records.

Does someone know why this occurs? And if so could you help me with the solution? Thank you!

The settings in my table match the ones written in the code.

```
 <?php //header_title, title & footer_title
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

              $layout_id = 1;
              $h_title = mysql_prep($_POST["h_title"]);
              $b_title = mysql_prep($_POST["b_title"]);
              $f_title = mysql_prep($_POST["f_title"]);

                $query  = "UPDATE layout1 SET ";
                $query .= "h_title = '{$h_title}', ";
                $query .= "b_title = '{$b_title}', ";
                $query .= "f_title = '{$f_title}' ";
                $query .= "WHERE id = {$layout_id}";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
                    //success
                    $_SESSION["message"] = "header/footer/title updated";
                  } else {
                    $_SESSION["message"] = "Update failed";
                  }
            }
        ?>

            <form action="website_design.php" method="post">
              <h3>Edit header and footer titels</h3>
                <p>Header title:          <input type"text" name"h_title" value"" />
                <br><br>Website Title:    <input type"text" name"b_title" value"" />
                <br><br>Footer title:     <input type"text" name"f_title" value"" />
                </p>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit" />
            </form>
```

Comment: I am sorry, i checked it for hours, can not figure it out. if i press submit in the form i get an error and my database table gets empty. First time happening.

Comment: Can you show your `mysql_prep()` function? And you should learn how to use prepared statements instead. Also check for errors: [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: function mysql_prep($string) {
    global $connection;

    $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
    return $escaped_string;
  }

Comment: Is `"website_design.php"` another script that redirect to this script? I'm just guessing based on the symptom of undefined $_POST parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>Header title:          <input type"text" name"h_title" value"" />
<br><br>Website Title:    <input type"text" name"b_title" value"" />
<br><br>Footer title:     <input type"text" name"f_title" value"" />
</p>
```

Typo mistake. Missing `=` signs.

Should be `<input type="text" name="h_title" value="" />`.

Same for the other 2 lines.

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry for the late reaction.

Comment: That is always the problem when you are tired :p